# Escape exclamation mark python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to supply a password with an exclamation mark as part of a password to zipfile's `extractall` function with trouble:

```
zf.extractall(pwd="password2015!")
```

I had tried: supplying pwd as a string, this returned a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1228, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1290, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1129, in open
    raise TypeError("pwd: expected bytes, got %s" % type(pwd))
TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got <class 'str'>
```

I also tried supplying `pwd=password2015\!` however this produced a syntax error.

Does anyone know why this would return an error like this? I thought extractall was supposed to expect a string.

Comment: It's very clear "pwd: expected bytes, got <class 'str'>"

Comment: Like it says, it expects bytes. If you are on Python 3, the  string type is a sequence of Unicode code points, not a sequence of bytes. But as  long as the code points are all ASCII (or you know a  target encoding), they can be coerced to the right type.

Comment: Try zf.extractall(pwd=b"password2015!")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says, it's expecting *bytes*, not a `str`. Not sure why you think the exclamation mark is an issue at all. Use one of these:

```
zf.extractall(pwd=b'password2015!')
zf.extractall(pwd='password2015!'.encode('ascii'))
```

It's possible that the password is represented as different bytes in different encodings, and it needs to match exactly at the byte level with the zip file. Hence the function requires you to take care of the encoding yourself and pass it raw bytes instead of a character string.

Comment: Too bad the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) makes no mention of this important detail...